# initializing a nested structure array

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I am trying to initalize this nested structure array and my compiler keeps telling me that i have too many initializer values.   is there another way i can go about this? or could someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_BOOKS = 3;

struct BookInfo
{
   string title;
   double price;
};

struct Author
{
    string name;
    BookInfo books[NUM_BOOKS];
};

//Prototype
void showInfo(Author a[], int);


int main()
{
   Author a[] =
  {
    { "NONE", { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 } },
    { "NONE", { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 } },

    { "NONE", { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 } }
 };

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
showInfo(a, NUM_BOOKS);

return 0;
}

//This fucnction displays the array
void showInfo(Author a[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
{
    cout << "The author: " << a[i].name << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cout << "\t The title: " << a[i].books[j].title << ", ";
        cout << "\t The price: " << a[i].books[j].price << endl;
    }

}

cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array is also object, so you have to use {} to border it:

```
Author a[] =
{
 { "NONE", {{ "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }} },
 { "NONE", {{ "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }} },
 { "NONE", {{ "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }} }
};
```